# Azure devops: Trigger release based on work item status

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

we're in the process of migrating from our old change management system into Azure DevOps. Our existing tool deployed code based on the status of the work item, so when status was changed to "Ready for Test", it would move the code to test and "Ready for Production" status would trigger the move to production.

From my experience with Azure DevOps so far, it almost seems to be the opposite of this, you trigger a release to test and can then the status of the work item can be automatically changed to reflect.

I've done some research and seen that we have the ability to trigger builds via a HTTP request and that it is also possible to I have seen its possible to create Web Hooks that can call an HTTP request, but it looks like I'd need something in the middle to parse the request and call the relevant HTTP service to trigger a build.

Perhaps i'm missing something, but is it possible in Azure DevOps to trigger a build or release based on Work Item status and if not "out of the box" then can anyone offer any suggestions how I might be able to utilize the Web Hooks functionality?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Query Work Item" [gate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=vsts) to only deploy to a given environment if the specified query returns no results. There's no triggers for this, but you can trigger a release based on other criteria and rely on the gate passing to trigger the actual deployment.